# Как разбить по группам записи на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, сортировка

Каким образом статьи на сайте можно разбить по группам? Например человека интересует Web, он нажимает на кнопку web и появляются записи которые относятся к этой категории(я полагаю статьи заранее надо какими-то метками помечать).

Comment: Вам нужны, например, теги. Посмотрите на данный сайт. Вы задаёте вопрос и указываете темы, к которым он относится. Вот интересно, кто вам мешает подумать или посмотреть у "соседа"?

Comment: @ArchDemon, не знаю у какого "соседа" можно посмотреть. Открытого рассказа на эту тему не могу найти. Из подумать, идея тегов есть, но как фильтровать, решить не могу.

Comment: Всё зависит от того, откуда вы берете данные. SQL -  `where tag='web';`